# Existential and Universal Equivalence Proof

Tags: quantifiers, universal-algebra, formal-proofs

Taking

¬∀x:X.r≡∃x:X.¬r

Is there a way of actually formally proving this?  Not implementing it but proving how to go from a negated universal quantifier to a an existential with a negated element...

I understand the logic behind it, I just can't figure out how I can use definitions to exit the negation of the universal and swap it to an existential and negating the middle.

I'm simply conflicted as to whether I would be allowed to directly implement this rule or if I have to prove it.  (The question simply says formally proof something, the entire problem would be solved if I simply quote the above rule, follow it with a DeMorgan and a Double Negation)

Thank anybody with any insight on the above.

Comment: How to prove it depends on the formalism you are using. Sometimes one of the existential or universal quantifier is *defined* from the other by what is essentially this rule.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't mean quoting the proof, which I have done, but to work your way directly step by step through it, like for example eliminating a negation, eliminating the universal quantifier, introducing an existential, along with the negation.

So essentially through some form of inference or (ideally) 2 way definitions.

Comment: Again *that depends upon the formalism that you are using*. How are $\forall$ and $\exists$ defined?

Comment: Formally proof the following statement:
¬∀x:X . P ∧ Q ⊣ ⊢ ∃x:X ¬P ∨ ¬Q

The above is literally all I have to work with.  Some say the equivalence law I quoted above should only be used with Sets, but that's what these are as far as I know

Comment: That's all you have to work with? You walked into this class for the first time, the prof handed that out and told you prove it, and walked out without defining anything or developing the formal language? The book starts with this problem?

Comment: Well surely that question didn't drop out of nowhere.

Comment: Oh, no that's not what I meant... I'm just saying that's all the question gives me.  I have laws of inference (Eliminating the Universal, introducing it, elimination and introduction rules basically for all of those) and definitions, two ways and one way.

Comment: Primary problem is the only way I can think of of working this out would be to somehow move two steps into one, which is converting a universal quantifier into a negated existential which in turn negates its elements.  That's not something we've ever done before, in fact we've only taken things one step at a time.  Example eliminating a negation by proving the negation negative so a double negation becomes a positive, or eliminate the universal quantifier by quoting P[x/x] instead.  So is there any way of proving the Law I quoted or do I have no alternative besides quoting it and moving on?